# How to override anchor <a> element in material ui v3?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I have tried to override the  in typography with

```
root: {
      '&a':{
        color: '#FF6600'
      },
    },
```

but didn't work any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you try `!important`?

Comment: yeap didn't worked also tried 
color: 'inherit' but nothing

Comment: I'm able to change the color locally. Can you provide some reproducible code?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to change the color(style) of Material-UI `<Typography />` locally.

Mostly been used options would be considered as:

- Add style based on the provided CSS API - refer to [MUI Typography API document](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/)
- Override style using the nesting selector for elements and classes - you can find the details inside the browser dev tools

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  option1: {
    color: "red"
  },
  option2: {
    "&.MuiTypography-root": {
      color: "blue"
    }
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Typography
        variant="h5"
        component="h5"
        classes={{ root: classes.option1 }}
      >
        Use CSS API with attribute: root
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h5" component="h5" className={classes.option2}>
        Use nesting selector of className: MuiTypography-root
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]